# UITextField keyboard is not recognized by voice over accessibility but works without it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, accessibility, voiceover

I am new in the topic of accessibility and have a problem with the voice over function of iOS.

I have a very simple UIViewController with an UITextField in it (see Screenshot). 
The problem is that when I start editing the textfield (the keyboard is opening after I double tap the textfield) and trying to tap on the keyboard, in order to hear/write the characters, the voice over function makes the sound, which is indicating that there is nothing. So I am not able to type in any characters, because the voice over function doesn't recognise the keyboard.
When I am editing the textfield without voice over, it works fine and I'm able to use the keyboard.

I have installed a UITapGestureRecogniser, which is initialized in the *textFieldDidBeginEditing* function and removed in the *textFieldDidEndEditing* function:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(MyHideKeyboard)];
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer: tap];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(MyHideKeyboard)];
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.view removeGestureRecognizer: tap];
}
```

But also with disabling it, it doesn't work. Moreover there is not different when I am switching the UIKeyboardType from URL (standard) to any other one.
All in all I am not accessing the textfield property in another way than *_textfield.text*, so I can exclude programmatically changes.

Hope someone can help!

[image: ViewController Screenshot]

Comment: Does the same problem reproduce in a much smaller example (just a plain UITextField without any custom gesture recognizers)? If you swipe up with two fingers and wait for VoiceOver to navigate through all elements, does it find the keyboard keys then?

Comment: Weird, yes! If the textfield is editing and I swipe up with two fingers, voice over finds the keyboard and go through all letters. But after finishing the presentation it doesn't work to use the keyboard. It's the same problem as described above.

Comment: Did you found any solution?